# nginx could not logging with $request_body if nginx location set `return 200;`?

Tags: nginx, logging

nginx could not logging with $request_body if nginx location set `return 200;`, if `proxy_pass` is set, it can be obtained normally.

***I just want to get the request body and don't want to do subsequent processing actions.***

bros, how to fixed.

```
// nginx_logging.conf
log_format json_hook escape=json
    '{"at": "$time_iso8601",'
    '"request_data": "$request_body",'
    '"request_method": "$request_method",'
    '"remote_addr": "$remote_addr"}';


// vhost.conf
...
    location /req/path/ {
        access_log /var/log/hook.json json_hook;
        default_type application/json;
        return 200 '{"code": "200"}';         <--------- here!
        #proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:25372;
    }
...


// log file
// ----with `return 200;`----
{ "@timestamp": "2022-01-05T13:45:27+08:00","request_body": "" }
{ "@timestamp": "2022-01-05T13:46:30+08:00","request_body": "" }

// ----with `proxy_pass`----
{ "@timestamp": "2022-01-05T13:49:23+08:00","request_body": "productId=123456" }
{ "@timestamp": "2022-01-05T13:49:48+08:00","request_body": "{\"productId\": 123456, \"quantity\": 100}" }
```

Answer (score 0):

The compromise solution: use echo service instead of response service.

```
# ngx_myserver.conf
# echo server.
server {
    listen 12001;
    server_name 127.0.0.1;
    location / {
        default_type application/json;
        return 200 '{"code": 200}';
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mydomain;

    location /req/path/ {
        access_log /var/log/hook.json json_log;
        default_type application/json;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:12001;
    }
}
```